# corregir espacios entre numero decimales

Tags: python

Feliz dia de reyes a todos y todas. Llevo con un programa en python un par de días y ahora que he llegado al final, me doy cuenta que he tengo que afinar.
Estos dias, entre otras muchas cosas, he conseguido corregir las posibles erratas de puntuación que puede tener un texto con este código:

```
 def correcciones_espacios(texto):
        texto = texto.replace('  ', '')
        texto = texto.replace('. ', '.')
        texto = texto.replace(' .', '.')
        texto = texto.replace('.', '. ')
        texto = texto.replace(':', ': ')
        texto = texto.replace(';', '; ')
        texto = texto.replace(';  ', '; ')
        texto = texto.replace(',', ', ')
        texto = texto.replace('.    ', '.\n')
        texto = texto.replace('  ', ' ')
        texto = texto.replace(' -', ':\n-')
        return texto
def mayusc_correcciones(text):
    text = correcciones_espacios(texto)
    text = ". ".join(oracion.capitalize() for oracion in text.split(". "))
    return text
```

Pero claro, qué pasa si el texto tiene decimales? Pues que me separa los números tras la coma como se lo pido. Entonces, no se como decirle que me respete eso sin cargarme el resto.

Gracias!!!!!

Comment: Sin expresiones regulares y sólo con `replace()` es muy complejo. Puedes, por ejemplo, una vez hechas tus transformaciones, hacer esta otra: `replace(". 0", ".0")`, para quitar el espacio que habías puesto entre el punto y el 0 (o usando coma, en vez de punto, si el separador de decimales era coma). Y así repetir con todos los dígitos de 0 a 9. Es tedioso, pero funcionará. Claro que eso fallará si una "frase" comienza por dígito, pero es que el número de casos posibles crece con cada nueva pregunta tuya :-) En algún momento hay que parar!

Comment: Ya lo creo!! A este paso lo siguiente será eliminar caracteres en ucraniano...creo que voy a por un trozo de rosco y santas pascuas. Solo me queda grabar cada salida en .text y listo.